# Incorrect value from php/mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, function

Afternoon,

I have a function here where I am trying to return a simple value of 0 if there are no records where a user has a role of Administrator or 1 if they do.  The command line SQL works absolutely fine, however when running it via the page it always returns a value of 4, which is the number of records in the table.

Totally confused, looking at it so long, any ideas?  As I say the query when run directly in mysql returns the correct, so I am not sure why it is returning 4 every time.

Thanks in advance.

```
    function userHasRole($role)
    {
include '../includes/db-connect.inc.php';
echo $_SESSION['username'];
try
{
    $sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM users
        INNER JOIN userrole ON users.id = userid 
        INNER JOIN role ON roleid = role.id;
        WHERE username = :username AND role.id = :roleId";

    $s = $PDO->prepare($sql);
    $s->bindValue(':username', $_SESSION['username']);
    $s->bindValue(':roleId', $role);
    $s->execute();
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
    $error = 'Error searching for author roles.';
    echo $error;
    exit();
}


$row = $s->fetch();
if ($row[0] > 0)
{
    return TRUE;
}
else
{
    return FALSE;
}

}
```

Comment: Do you get any errors? Do you call the function? I don't see any call of the function.

Comment: Sorry, should have added that, I use if (!userHasRole('Administrator'))... in another page and it all works fine, I mean if I change the if ($row[0] == 1) then it locks me out as it of course keeps returning 4 so it's all working as it should apart from managing to list the wrong count of users that have administrator.

Comment: Suggestion for debugging: display all of $row right before you check the value of $row[0]. Suggestion for writing SQL: just say "select 1 from users..." instead of count(*). You don't really need the actual count, and doing it that way should be faster anyway. Once you see what is in $row, if anything, that should tell you the problem.

Comment: Thanks, I did output the value of row and it's set to 4 regardless of what user is logged in.  And yes I could select 1 however I am really trying to understand why it is returning 4 when the Query when run on the command line returns only 0 or 1.

Comment: Hmm. I was hoping that showing the *entire* structure, not just that element of the structure, would show you the answer. Another option, without really thinking about it, is to name the field (for example, 'select count(*) as x from ...' and then check $row['X'] instead of $row[0]. Might help, and I think that is better form. I would also try hard coding values into the SQL, to try to see if it is your SQL or the PHP causing the issue. If it is the binding itself that has issues, then the $row variable is not where your problem really is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a semicolon where you don't want one -- after the 2nd inner join. Get rid of that and try again. I think the WHERE clause is totally ignored.

```
$sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM users
        INNER JOIN userrole ON users.id = userid 
        INNER JOIN role ON roleid = role.id;
        WHERE username = :username AND role.id = :roleId";
```

Sorry, I should have noticed that right off. It probably does not throw an error because PHP doesn't even allow you to run multiple SQL statements, in a simplistic effort to prevent SQL injection. So everything after the semicolon is ignored.

Comment: MJB, just lol.  As soon as I read your first line I was like, what is he on about... Then I looked at role.id; and just hung my head in shame..

Thank you very much for spotting it, hence it was returning 4 as it counted 4 and identified none!  AGGHHHHHH!  :P

Comment: Happens to the best of us. I was pretty embarrassed, too, having commented 3 times without noticing it.

Comment: It was working fine when I was trying it directly in mysql which was annoying me, but of course as I was typing it into the command line I was not making the mistake of adding the ; sigh! :)